# How to use parenthesis in dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, parentheses

Following is my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

all: /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ (a-b)
        @tar cjvf 1.tar.bz2 --exclude=*~ /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ \(a-b\)
```

It didn't work. The problem is the parenthesis in dependency. Adding `\` before `(` and `)` also didn't work. The error is this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/wu/qqaa/homepage 1 2 3/icons (a-b)', needed by `all'. Stop
```

The directory /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage 1 2 3/icons (a-b) does exist. It seemed that parenthesis couldn't be used in dependency. Is it correct? Or do I miss something?

Sound that colon also couldn't be used in dependency.

I wrote a bash shell script to backup my system. I used `make` and `tar` to backup. Using `make` is to only update the newer files and tar the directory. The problem is that the names of many files have colon or parenthesis and they have special meaning in Makefile. It results in the above problem.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that parentheses mark archive members and seem to be unescapeable. The usual tricks are backslash-escape and escaping by using a variable:

```
.PHONY : all
leftparen:=(
rightparen:=)
all: /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ $(leftparen)a-b$(rightparen)
        @tar cjvf 1.tar.bz2 --exclude=*~ "$@"
```

And since both don't work in this case, you'll probably have to live with this limitation or file a bug against GNU make.

Comment: @thilton, Using a variable didn't work for me(I am using Mac lion OS). Does it work in your OS?

Comment: @warem: Like the post said, it didn't work, sorry. Just posted one of the usual alternatives as a reference and to note for others that it didn't work.

Comment: @thilton: I am sorry that I didn't notice the sentence below your codes.

Comment: It works perfectly well by me and it wasn't easy to find this stellar answer on the SE.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had this problem with a Makefile that I was using in Windows.   The compiler is a 32-bit version of MinGW64-W32.

`gcc --version` shows:  `gcc (i686-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.1.0`

`make --version` shows: `GNU Make 3.81`

I was writing a Makefile that needed to include directories that changed (ie, the include directories for the 32-bit compiler are different than the include directories for the 64-bit compiler).   I needed to include something like:
`-IC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/gtk+-3.6.4_win32/include/gtk-3.0`

For example.  I had the same problem, when I tried to compile, the compiler would error out about ( on line 0 or something.   My solution was simple.   I just had to use double quotes, like this:

`-I"C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/gtk+-3.6.4_win32/include/gtk-3.0"`

Using the double quotes worked.   It allowed me to successfully compile my program.

A side note here.   Normally, in Linux, for a directory with spaces, we need something like:

`-I"C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/mingw-w64/gtk+-3.6.4_win32/include/gtk-3.0"`

with the \ before the space.    In the Makefile, **if I use \'s for spaces, with the double quote, the program does not compile.**   I believe the Makefile believes the \'s are actually part of the directories name, when I use double quotes.

For your code, try something like:

```
.PHONY: all

all: /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ (a-b)
        @tar cjvf 1.tar.bz2 --exclude=*~ "/Users/wu/qqaa/homepage 1 2 3/icons (a-b)"
```

If that doesn't work, then try something like:

```
.PHONY: all

all: /Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ (a-b)
        @tar cjvf 1.tar.bz2 --exclude=*~ "/Users/wu/qqaa/homepage\ 1\ 2\ 3/icons\ (a-b)"
```

Anyway, good luck.